# How to parse a JSON having multiple object in an array using mvc5?

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a web API which return the JSON when called. The problem is it returns array of JSON having multiple object. I need to parse it for my class to create a grid.

You can check [my api here](http://www.myopsarc.com/OpsArcWebAPI/api/Onboarding).

I'm getting following error while parsing it

> Blockquote
>   "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'OpsArc.Models.OnBoardingDetailsWithResourceDTO' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1.'"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks..i will keep in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this website (JSON2CSharp)](http://json2csharp.com/) to translate your json output into their respective classes. You'll get the following output

```
public class ThisResource
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object empRec { get; set; }
    public int createdBy { get; set; }
    public object payrollId { get; set; }
    public int resourceTypeID { get; set; }
    public string resourceTypeValue { get; set; }
    public string resourceTypeStoredValue { get; set; }
    public string ssn { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string middleName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string localEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int resourceStatusId { get; set; }
    public object resourceStatusValue { get; set; }
    public object resourceStatusStoredValue { get; set; }
    public object vendorId { get; set; }
    public object alertRec { get; set; }
    public object alertNote { get; set; }
    public object divRec { get; set; }
    public object repRec { get; set; }
    public object hold { get; set; }
    public object holdNote { get; set; }
    public object cdid { get; set; }
    public object shortNotes { get; set; }
    public object doNotPlace { get; set; }
    public object modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public object lastModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ts { get; set; }
}

public class ThisBoardingDetails
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string resourceOnboardingID { get; set; }
    public int desiredResourceTypeID { get; set; }
    public int offerExpires { get; set; }
    public object desiredResourceTypeValue { get; set; }
    public object desiredResourceTypeStoredValue { get; set; }
    public string jobOrderID { get; set; }
    public string backgroundCheckID { get; set; }
    public int emailID { get; set; }
    public string requestDate { get; set; }
    public object onboardingRequest { get; set; }
    public int onboardingStatusCode { get; set; }
    public string resourceID { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ThisResource thisResource { get; set; }
    public ThisBoardingDetails thisBoardingDetails { get; set; }
}
```

You will need to fix a few things, but it's a good enough resource to give you a start.

Comment: thanks for ur reply i have alredy created classes from this website but geeting error while parsing data into it

Comment: ..then you need to update your answer with the relevant errors and information. As it stands your question is unhelpful in helping you,